# Need help in accessning Kubernetes UI

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes

I have recently installed Kubernetes in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

But i am unable to access the kube UI. Below are details.

Kubectl Version:

> u64@ubuntu64:~$ kubectl version Client Version:
>   version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"7", GitVersion:"v1.7.5",
>   GitCommit:"17d7182a7ccbb167074be7a87f0a68bd00d58d97",
>   GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-08-31T09:14:02Z",
>   GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"} Server
>   Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"7", GitVersion:"v1.7.5",
>   GitCommit:"17d7182a7ccbb167074be7a87f0a68bd00d58d97",
>   GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-08-31T08:56:23Z",
>   GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Kubectl Config View:

> u64@ubuntu64:~$ kubectl config view apiVersion: v1 clusters:
>   - cluster:
>       certificate-authority-data: REDACTED
>       server: https://130.211.115.230   name: amazing-insight-172917_kubernetes contexts:
>   - context:
>       cluster: amazing-insight-172917_kubernetes
>       user: amazing-insight-172917_kubernetes   name: amazing-insight-172917_kubernetes current-context:
>   amazing-insight-172917_kubernetes kind: Config preferences: {} users:
>   - name: amazing-insight-172917_kubernetes   user:
>       client-certificate-data: REDACTED
>       client-key-data: REDACTED
>       token: GV0sJB4PXYgQofLPypELZeMLakr5bFA6
>   - name: amazing-insight-172917_kubernetes-basic-auth   user:
>       password: opYOctdphtqIBZWE
>       username: admin

When i am trying to access the URL https://130.211.115.230/ui/ i am getitng the error

```
User "system:anonymous" cannot get path "/ui/".: "No policy matched."
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
kubectl proxy --port=8001 --kubeconfig=<path-to-kubeconfig>
```

and then go to `127.0.0.1:8001/ui`.

You can skip the kubeconfig if your kubectl context is correctly set.

Comment: I have found below files with that name and i am confused on what fille need to be re-directed there. Could please suggest me ?

u64@ubuntu64:~$ sudo locate "kubeconfig"
/home/u64/google-cloud-sdk/.install/.backup/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/container/kubeconfig.py
/home/u64/google-cloud-sdk/.install/.backup/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/container/kubeconfig.pyc
/home/u64/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/container/kubeconfig.py
/home/u64/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/container/kubeconfig.pyc
u64@ubuntu64:~$

Answer (score 0):

How have you installed Kubernetes on Ubuntu? If it is with `kubeadm` it enables RBAC by default with prevents unprivileged access to the cluster. You need to explicitly grant dashboard access to resources.

As mentioned at https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard#deployment create the dashboard using the following command which will also setup the RBAC rules:

```
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.4.0/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml
```

or **With Helm**

```
helm repo add kubernetes-dashboard https://kubernetes.github.io/dashboard/
helm install kubernetes-dashboard kubernetes-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard
```

Comment: I tried and i got a message that they are already there.

u64@ubuntu64:~$ kubectl create -f https://git.io/kube-dashboard
serviceaccount "kubernetes-dashboard" created
clusterrolebinding "kubernetes-dashboard" created
Error from server (AlreadyExists): error when creating "https://git.io/kube-dashboard": deployments.extensions "kubernetes-dashboard" already exists
Error from server (AlreadyExists): error when creating "https://git.io/kube-dashboard": services "kubernetes-dashboard" already exists
u64@ubuntu64:~$

Comment: Why don't you delete the deployment and service and then try again? `kubectl -n kube-system delete deployment,svc kube-dasboard`

Answer (score 0):

Create the dashboard as follow
`kubectl create -f https://rawgit.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/kuber
netes-dashboard.yaml`

View the `username` and `password` by running `kubectl config view`

Access the Dashboard as folow `https://<kubernetes-master>/ui`, where `<kubernetes-master>` is IP address or domain name of the Kubernetes master

This is a screen shot of the Dashboard I just setup from steps above

[image]

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/

Answer (score 0):

Your dashboard is up and running. You can access it by executing this command on you workstation:

```
kubectl --server=https://130.211.115.230/ --insecure-skip-tls-verify --username=admin --password=opYOctdphtqIBZWE proxy
```

Thereafter http://127.0.0.1/ui

**Btw, anyone in the world can go do this as you accidently leaked the credentials.**

Comment: No they can't access i am getting below error. :)

more than one authentication method found for amazing-insight-172917_kubernetes; found [token basicAuth], only one is allowed

But any way i am able to access now. I haven't started the proxy server. I have started it and i am able o access it.

Comment: Sure they can. Just ran this successfully: `kubectl --server=https://130.211.115.230/ --insecure-skip-tls-verify --username=admin --password=opYOctdphtqIBZWE get pod --all-namespaces`

Answer (score 0):

This is been rectified by starting the proxy. Below is the command

```
kubectl proxy
```

and below is the command output. After wards I am able to access the UI.

> Starting to serve on 127.0.0.1:8001

Thanks for all your contributions.